# Why is Android Retrofit 2 receiving StreamResetException (INTERNAL_ERROR), but elsewhere works properly?

Tags: android, https, retrofit2

### Issue

I am using Retrofit 2 in an Android application to get RSS feeds. I currently have 21 other feeds within the app, all of which I am able to successfully get with this Retrofit configuration. However, I am running into trouble with getting a specific feed.

The feed is from US News & World Report at `https://www.usnews.com/rss/news`. I am able to retrieve it in my browser and in Postman. However, in my app, I receive a `StreamResetException` with the following stacktrace:

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:148)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:97)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Considering that I can access this feed elsewhere, I am under the belief that there is something wrong with how I have my Retrofit instance configured within the Android app for this specific RSS feed.

---

### My Code

My Retrofit instance is set up this way, injected via Hilt:

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }
```

The interface I use with the instance is set up as such:

```
interface RssManager {
    @GET
    suspend fun getFeed(@Url baseUrl: String): Response<String>
}
```

---

### What I've Tried So Far

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with how to debug problems with Retrofit, and I was not able to find any questions on StackOverflow that exactly matches this issue. Therefore, I decided to try modifying my Retrofit code in a few different ways to see if I could produce a different or desirable result, some of which were suggested in similar-ish Retrofit questions:

- I tried removing the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` from the
  `OkHttpClient.Builder`, but this produced the same error.
- I tried adding a `Protocol` to the `OkHttpClient.Builder`:
  `Protocol.HTTP_1_1` results in a timeout;
  `Protocol.H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE` results in an error stating
  `H2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE cannot be used with HTTPS`; the other protocols
  crash the app with an error stating `protocols must contain h2_prior_knowledge or http/1.1`.
- I tried adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the app's
  manifest, which had no effect. From my understanding, this is only
  helpful for accessing HTTP (and the feed is HTTPS), but I figured I
  would cover my bases before opening a question.
- I tried comparing this feed with others that do work, along with the
  response & settings in Postman, but I am just not knowledgeable
  enough about this topic to clearly see if there is anything relevant.

Beyond this, I am uncertain how to proceed or debug. If I can provide additional info or relevant code snippets, please let me know in the comments, and I will edit this question.